# How to change JSON before mapping by RESTKIT

Tags: objective-c, json, mapping, restkit

I am using RESTKIT to map the JSON returned from server.

The JSON result obtained from server is as follows

```
{"term":"Zh","results":{"users":[{"id":{"$oid":"4ebe59970a614e0019000055"},"term":"some text","score":1}]}
```

How can I convert the above JSON result to the below:

```
{"results":{"users":[{"uid":"4ebe59970a614e0019000055","text":"some text"}]}
```

Also, where can I do this so that the RESTKIT mapping will use the converted JSON instead of the initial one?

Below is the loader class that I am using to manage the JSON and mappings

```
-(void)getObjects
{
    RKObjectManager *sharedManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    [sharedManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:self.resourcePath delegate:self];
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {
    NSLog(@"Loaded PAYLOAD successfully for %@, with response %@", self.resourcePath , [response bodyAsString]  );
}


- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects 
{
}


+ (void)setManagerAndMappings
{
    RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:SERVER_URL];
    RKObjectMappingProvider* provider = [[RKObjectMappingProvider new] autorelease];

    //User Object Mapping
    RKObjectMapping* userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
    [userMapping mapKeyPath:@"_id" toAttribute:@"uid"];

    [userMapping mapAttributes:@"avatar_url",@"created_at",@"email",@"name",@"nickname",@"follower_count",@"following_count",@"answer_count",@"new_notification_count",@"new_questions_count",@"is_following",@"facebook_configured",@"twitter_configured",@"description",@"approved",@"type", nil];
    [provider setMapping:userMapping forKeyPath:@"user"];

}
```

Comment: why would you convert the JSON obtained by the server? It would be better to directly modify the contents on the server back. If you can not change the object returned, simply map the return as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the only solution is to modify the returned object at the server level.
If you can't,just map that returns the server.

Comment: As you can see, response.body is readonly property, and there is no methods to change body. Maybe you can change RestKit API code for allow this, but I think it would be a misuse of API.

[RKResponse Class Reference]http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKResponse.html#

Answer (score 4):

@Shocks answer is appealing, unfortunately it is valid a for version before 0.20.

Anyway, a similar solution is available for 0.20 too, using an implementation of RKSerialization:

```
@interface ORRKJsonSerialization : NSObject <RKSerialization>
@end
```

and implementing

```
@implementation ORRKJsonSerialization

+ (id)objectFromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
{
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:error];
    // change your data before mapping
    return result;
}

+ (NSData *)dataFromObject:(id)object error:(NSError **)error
{
    return [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:error];
}

@end
```

then during the setup:

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[ORRKJsonSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/json"];
```

HTH

Comment: worth notice that "serializations are searched in the reverse order of their registration. If a registration is made for an already registered MIME Type, the new registration will take precedence."

Comment: If you need it just for one method you can unregister the class using [RKMIMETypeSerialization unregisterClass:[ORRKJsonSerialization class]];

Answer (score 3):

There is a willMapData: selector in the [RKObkectLoaderDelegate](http://restkit.org/api/0.9/Protocols/RKObjectLoaderDelegate.html#//api/name/objectLoader%3awillMapData%3a) that is invoked just after parsing has completed. The mappableData argumet is mutable, so i guess you can change the data just before the object mapping will take place.

Answer (score 3):

use `RKObjectRequestOperation.setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock:`.

In swift:

```
    let request = RKObjectManager.sharedManager().requestWith...
    let operation = RKObjectManager.sharedManager().managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest(request, managedObjectContext: context, success: { operation, result in
        // success
    }, failure: { operation, error in
        // failure
    })
    operation.setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock { deserializedResponse -> AnyObject! in
        // Here to transform response
        return transformResponse(deserializedResponse)
    }
    RKObjectManager.sharedManager().enqueueObjectRequestOperation(operation)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register your own parser.  I had to do this to modify and clean-up some JSON from a legacy system.

```
[[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] setParserClass:[MyJSONParser class]
                                          forMIMEType:@"application/json"];
```

And then create your own:

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import <RestKit/RKJSONParserJSONKit.h>
#import <RestKit/JSONKit.h>
#import <RestKit/RKLog.h>

@interface EFJSONParser : RKJSONParserJSONKit
- (NSDictionary *)objectFromString:(NSString *)string error:(NSError **)error;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to editing the response of JSOn. the better way is only to do changes in server side as said by @beber